# Does ballistic electron transport require low temperatures?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, quantum-electrodynamics

It is my understanding that ballistic conduction mainly occurs at very short distances. Now a redditor claimed it only takes place under extremely cold temperatures but I found an article published 22 years ago describing room temperature ballistic conduction in carbon nanotubes.

Comment: The work in the 1980's in GaAs required low temperatures to reduce the thermionic contributions to the measured currents. A different material system may well have a different definition of what is "low" enough to suppress other current contributions.

Comment: @JonCuster FTR: The ad hoc definition of low temperature I am using here is << room temperature(as in cold enough to be considered cryogenic).

Comment: Well, I'd believe an actual journal article or two over some random commentator (Reddit or here, including me). I'm not up enough on the area to really answer the question. Can you add a link to the article you found?